If I manage to successfully apply integration by parts, will it always give me a right answer?
I came across a differential equation when studying for an exam and I have a questions regarding integration by parts. The question asks you to solve the differential equation:
$$(x-a)\frac{dy}{dx}=y-x $$
And tells you to use the substitution $y=(x-a)u$
After applying the sub, I got to this stage:
$$\int du=\int \frac{-x}{(x-a)^2}dx$$
At this point I opted to use integration by parts which would give
$$u+c=x(x-a)^{-1}-\int(x-a)^{-1}dx$$
And then after solving that second integral it would give
$$u+c=x(x-a)^{-1}-\ln{|x-a|}+c$$
However when I see the markscheme for this question it actually does not use integration by parts, instead it uses another method to split the fraction as follows:
$$-\int \frac{x-a+a}{(x-a)^{2}}dx=-\int\frac{1}{x-a}+\frac{a}{(x-a)^{2}}dx$$
When you solve via this method the answer is:
$$u+c=a(x-a)^{-1}-\ln{|x-a|}+c$$
This is very similar to the answer I got with integration by parts except in the first term, the $x$ is changed by an $a$ so it is clearly a different answer.
My question basically is: is this normal? Can a single differential equation give two distinct general solutions? I know I still need to change the $u$ back to in terms of $y$ but even after I do that I will get different answers for each of the methods I showed. Have I done something wrong in my integration by parts? Is it just not a valid method for this integral? What is happening here, maybe both are correct solutions which would mean that using different methods to integrate yields different solutions which I am not sure if thats accurate to say, if somebody knows please confirm.
Thank you so much for reading

It's not a different answer. Try subtracting the two solutions (no need for the constants of integration) and simplify. You should get a constant.

If you use integration by parts correctly and under the appropriate conditions, the result will have no choice but being correct.

Both are correct since
$$\frac{x}{x-a}-\ln|x-a|+c=\left(\frac{a}{x-a}+1\right)-\ln|x-a|+c=\frac{a}{x-a}-\ln|x-a|+c^\prime$$
where $c^\prime=c+1$. Integration by parts is a mathematical result, it always works correctly if you use it correctly.
Hope this helps. :)
